# Can't log into psql on fresh Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using Docker Compose with the official [postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) on Docker Hub. After I run `docker-compose up`, I shell into my PostgreSQL container and run `psql -U postgres`. But when I do, I get the following error:

```
bash-5.1# psql -U postgres
psql: error: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

Here's the relevant part of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
 ---
# Docker Compose 2.4 is for local development
# https://www.heroku.com/podcasts/codeish/57-discussing-docker-containers-and-kubernetes-with-a-docker-captain - Source on that.
version: '2.4'

services:
    postgres:
    image: postgres:13.1-alpine
    mem_limit: 256m
    volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data:delegated
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
    environment:
        PSQL_HISTFILE: /root/log/.psql_history
        POSTGRES_USER: my_app
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pgpassword
    restart: on-failure
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 2s
        retries: 10
    logging:
        driver: none

volumes:
    postgresql:
    storage:
```

Why could it be that my `postgres` user isn't getting created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the postgres superuser as `POSTGRES_USER: my_app` (see [the readme on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) for details), but try to login with username `postgres` (`psql -U postgres`), which does not exist. If we switch it to `my_app`, it should work. Same goes for the health check.

Alternatively, we could set the `POSTGRES_USER` to, e.g., `postgres` or `root` (or whatever we want) and provide initialization scripts to the container's directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. All `*.sql`-scripts in this folder will be executed on database startup. A common approach is to mount a host-directory containing all scripts (e.g. creation of a new role, creation of a new database, and giving the new role ownership to this database) to this container-directory. An example can be found in [this bitbucket repository of mine](https://bitbucket.org/nextrpgdeveloper/untitled-rpg-webapp/src/develop/localdeployment/docker-compose.yml). We can just focus on the `postgres` container and the `postgres` directory, since those are the important parts.

Comment: You are correct: `psql -U my_app` worked. Thanks!